# call_user_func on methods

Tags: php, function, methods

Is there any difference between:

```
$callback = array(&$this, 'method');
$callback[0]->$callback[1]($args);
```

and

```
call_user_func(array(&$this, 'method'), $args);
```

?

Comment: The first is equivalent to: $x='method'; $this->$x($args); but because it's processing the function name at runtime, it has to use call_user_func

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't really seen the first example in use, but it seems valid and should be faster than `call_user_func()` as you don't have the overhead of calling another function.

UPDATE:

Also, you can't do this with `call_user_func()` if you have enabled the E_STRICT error level:

```
// ...

public function &example($foo)
{
    $this->bar = 'foo';
    return $this->bar;
}

// ...

$dummy = &$callback[0]->$callback[1]($args);
```

In that case, `call_user_func()` will trigger something like this to appear:

> PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be assigned by reference in php shell code on line X

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no difference between calling a variable method/function and using `call_user_func`.  I haven't run across a circumstance where I needed the latter.  By the way, you don't need to pass `$this` by reference; all objects are automatically passed by reference.

Answer (score 2):

No difference, but i prefer the second one for readability. First one is less clear and takes two lines...